# How to animate position of browser tab's title on tab change

Tags: javascript, user-interface, frontend, addeventlistener

I'm trying to animate the browser tab's title when that tab has been inactive for more than 1 second.
When I add the following snippet to the console, it works perfectly fine. However, when I try to call this inside an eventlistener for "visibilitychange", it does change the title however it fails to animate.

```
  msg = "Don't forget us" + msg;
  position = 0;
  function scrolltitle() {
    document.title = msg.substring(position, msg.length) + msg.substring(0, position); position++;
    if (position > msg.length);
    position = 0
    window.setTimeout("scrolltitle()",170);
  }
  scrolltitle();
```

Here is the full code I'm trying to run but failing to do so with the desired behaviour of animation:

````
const animate = () => {
  msg = ' ';
  msg = "Don't forget us" + msg;
  position = 0;
  function scrolltitle() {
    document.title = msg.substring(position, msg.length) + msg.substring(0, position); position++;
    if (position > msg.length);
    position = 0
    window.setTimeout("scrolltitle()",170);
  }
  scrolltitle();
};

document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
  if (document.hidden) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      animate();
    }, 1000);
  }
});```
````

Comment: what is that `;` after `if (position > msg.length)` ?

Comment: @ImanEmadi must be a typo. Removing it doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initialize your variable with `let` , your code doesn't work because `position` variable is not being updated

```
      const animate = () => {
    let msg = " ";
    msg = "Don't forget us" + msg;
    let position = 0;
    function scrolltitle() {
      console.log(position, msg.length);
      document.title =
        msg.substring(position, msg.length) + msg.substring(0, position);
      position++;
      if (position > msg.length) position = 0;
      setTimeout(() => {
        scrolltitle();
      }, 170);
    }
    scrolltitle();
  };

  document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
    if (document.hidden) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        animate();
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Another question, why is it that the 'animation' gets slowed down when the tab is inactive?

Comment: can't say for sure , but according to my experience , this can be because it's trying to do actions in a short time and repeat it again , that's much performance , specially when page comes up with much more scripts , but there can be other reasons too ...

Comment: thannk you! Final question! can you give me a clue as to how to stop the animation once document.hidden === false?

Comment: each timeout or interval returns an ID , which can be used for clearTimeout or clearInterval , you can set an interval instead of timeout and store it's returned ID in a variable  , then clear it when your desired event triggers